# How do not lock/sleep MacBook when you close the laptop lid?

Tags: macos

I would like the MacBook not to sleep and or lock when closing the laptop lid. I would like to lock and sleep it only manually. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: There's already dozens of answers provided to prevent sleep when closing the lid.  Please use the Search function to find and try the answers already provided.

Answer (score 0):

To enable laptop sleeping with closed lid:

```
sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1
```

To re-enable laptop sleeping:

```
sudo pmset -b sleep 5; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0
```